# For a 90 day Egypt tourist visa how do I prove the duration of my stay?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, south-african-citizens, egypt

I would like to apply for a 90 day tourist visa for Egypt. I intend to apply at the consulate in Berlin via post not in person. This is for a South African passport.

The website (http://www.egyptian-embassy.de/konsulat/visa-auswahl-formular) requires a proof-of-stay-duration (Reisedauer) to be submitted with the application. Examples for stay-duration are hotel booking or rental contract.

I have neither as I intend to backpack through Egypt. I do have a return flight but the website says a flight booking is not accepted as proof of stay duration.

**Questions**

1. Will the Egyptian Consulate issue me a visa if I explain my intention in my application, i.e. how strict is the proof-of-stay-duration requirement?
2. Or should I book a hotel for the first night?

**What I have tried**

- Phoning the consulate but nobody answers.
- Emailed and received a reply which is a copy of the information on the website.

Comment: Could you 'book' a tour then cancel it which lasts the duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Embassy's directions are explicit, and your email reply from the Embassy appears to confirm that it does not make exceptions. It also suggests that it might be wise to draft an itinerary, and book accommodations for more than just the evening of your arrival.

> Citizens from the country selected above [South Africa] should apply for their long-term visa with a validity of more than 30 and up to 90 days in advance in Germany. The processing of the application takes about one week. The visa can be applied for at the earliest three months before the planned start of the journey.
>
> For the application is required (for each applicant):   
>  
>    - Passport in the original (at least six months valid for the planned entry)
>    - Copy of the first page of the passport 
>   - **Proof of travel time, eg by hotel booking or rental agreement - a mere flight booking is not enough.** 
>   - 2 biometric passport photos 
>   - completed and signed visa application (http://www.egyptian-embassy.de/images/visaform.pdf) 
>   - copy of the residence permit (if available)
>   - 22 euros in cash (per applicant, for Germans), 38 euros in cash (all other nationalities).